# How to get list from Firestore in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get the data from a list in Firestore. I searched but don't find any results for this, even in the Firebase Documents.

The list is a List of Strings. Let's call him `Users`.
The `Users` list brings a list of names.
How can I get just the values from the Firestore?

The code I'm using is

```
firestoreClient.collection("Users").get().addOnSuccessListener { result -> }
```

What do I do inside the `addOnSuccessListener` method?

I Already tried something like `document.data` but don't work for a list, because a list brings Any data type.

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
var userNameList = listOf<String>()             //<-- To store list of user's name
db.collection("Users").get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
     for (document in documents) {
        
        // assuming the attribute name is 'userName'
         val userName = document["userName"].toString()  

       // add the userName to the list
         userNameList += userName        
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Kotlin, the simplest method to read user documents would be to call get() and attach a listener. And in code, it would be as simple as:

```
val usersRef = Firebase.firestore.collection("Users")
usersRef.get().addOnCompleteListener {
    if (it.isSuccessful) {
        var names = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (document in it.result) {
            val name = document.getString("name")
            names.add(name)
        }
        //Do what you need to do with the list
        Log.d(TAG,"${names.size}")
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "${it.exception?.message}") //Never ignore potential errors!
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do like that I Receive an DocumentSnapshot for response. I need to get that data: https://prnt.sc/yvAjPnevAbx8 and I receive a data like that https://prnt.sc/Kziu5saqthGg  https://prnt.sc/U7OiRleiRnKv I need to know how I can filter the response by the 'Users' key and get the animeId arraylist. Can you help me?

Comment: If you have any other question that derives from this one, then it's considered a new question and should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: No, just it. Thanks for the time!